# I have problems with lsp server rust-analyzer

Tags: rust-cargo, neovim, language-server-protocol, rustup

When I trying to launch some .rs files (rust files) I catch error in neovim:

```
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:22: Error executing lua: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:23: Vim(append):Error
 executing lua callback: Vim:E475: Invalid value for argument cmd: 'cargo' is not executable
```

My lsp.lua config file is empty, because all servers I installed from Mason, I also reinstall neovim, reinstalled runtime directory etc what was described in internet but nothing changed((((
Small thing about this all, this error was not there until i reinstalled rust to rustup from other rust version (I forgot the name), because I think my autocompletion didn't work because rust version or something else related with my rust blocked this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, neovim printed your problem:

```
Vim:E475: Invalid value for argument cmd: 'cargo' is not executable
```

It seemst that you haven't installed `cargo` which you'll get if you install rust. I'd highly recommend to install [`rustup`](https://rustup.rs/) with the package manager of your linux-distribution and execute:

```
rustup default stable
```

afterwards. This should install your relevant tools to develop with rust (including your missing program `cargo`).

Comment: do I need to create a PATH variable .cargo/bin when I install rustup? (I use fedora)

Comment: No you don't, just install rustup with `sudo dnf install rustup`, re-open your terminal, by closing your current terminal and open a new terminal-window, and execute `rustup default stable` and you should be fine.